# VS Code explorer disappearing on clicking any of the items below explorer in sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code latest version 1.56.2 in Ubuntu 18.04. The explorer option is getting hidden in side bar on clicking other items below explorer in side bar. How to show  it always in side bar rather than using `ctrl+shift+e` every time

[image: explorer disappearing on clicking source control and Run and Debug]

[image]

Comment: Can you right-click on the sidebar and see if the explorer tab is disabled?

Comment: @burningalc yes it is disabled. working now after enabling it. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [@burningalc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12569596/burningalc)'s comment, the explorer tab (or any other tab) can be disabled in a sidebar. In this case the disabled tab disappears when clicking on any other tab. The tabs can be re-enabled by right-click and check the tab in a contextual menu.

Comment: right clicking works! thanks.

Comment: Experience same Explorer icon disappearing, but when i right click on activity Bar to check the explorer again, the explorer has gone away so i can't click on it. Have an idea ?